# How to turn List<ExpandoObject> into Group<key, value> of unique values?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using `CsvHelper` to parse a CSV file.  I'm using `helper.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();` which returns a `List<ExpandoObject>`.

Each `ExpandoObject` in the list represents a row in the CSV file and each property of the `ExpandoObject` corresponds to a column of the CSV file where the property is named based on the column heading.

**EDIT** I'm receiving many different CSV files each with different headers and values.  The idea here is to have the Controller return a list of the headers in the CSV file along with all the unique values found in each column.

**Example** (CSV data)

```
ID, Name, State, Age
1,Mickey,FL,50
2,Minnie,FL,48
3,Donald,AK,48
```

**I'd have something like this (`List<IDictionary<string,object>>`)**

```
var results = helper.GetRecords<dynamic>();
var item = (IDictionary<string,object>) results.First();
foreach(var prop in (IDictionary<string,object>)item){
   console.WriteLine($"{prop.Key} : {prop.Value}");
}
//ID : 1
//Name: Mickey
//State: FL
//Age: 50
```

**What I'm after**

Since each `IDictionary<string,object>` in the `List` contains the same set of `Keys`, I want to wind up with an `Group<key,List<uniquevalues>>` like so:

```
Group Key: "ID"
   Values: ["1","2","3"]

Group Key: "Name"
   Values: ["Mickey","Minnie","Donald"]

Group Key: "State"
   Values: ["FL","AK"]

Group Key: "Age"
   Values: ["50","48"]
```

**Note** the solution doesn't necessarily have to be a Group -- it could be an `IDictionary<key, List<unique value>>`.

Comment: If your file has well defined column headers like you show, why use `dynamic` at all? You could create a class to match and read to it so things will be much simpler?

Comment: Because, that is just one of many CSV files that may be passed in to my controller.  Each CSV may have different headers/values.  I gave the CSV example to just make it clearer what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is to flatten your list before grouping by each key/property and its associated values. This will produce the results you are looking for.

```
    var group = results
                .SelectMany(r => r)
                .GroupBy(g => g.Key)
                .Select(g => new { 
                    Key = g.Key, 
                    Values = string.Join(",", g.Select(r => r.Value))
                });

    foreach(var r in group)
        Console.WriteLine("Key: " + r.Key + ", Values: " + r.Values);
```

[See working fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ao0CaG).

HTH

Comment: The `SelectMany` was the piece that I was missing!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

High level solution:
use projection (Select) to create your required 4 new objects (can be anonymous or pre-defined objects). 
Then you can use union operator with the same objects to remove duplicates. (if you  anonymous types there will no need to pass custom Equality Comparer)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a well defined set of headers, you can create a class to represent your records, and read it like this:

```
var results = helper.GetRecords<Person>();
```

Here, `Person` would be the class representing your `CSV` columns, something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then upon reading, you can iterate through each property and create a list of unique values.

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
foreach (var prop in typeof(Person).GetProperties())
{
    list.Add(prop.Name, results.Select(x => prop.GetValue(x)).Distinct());
}
```